# Datos no insertan con consulta preparada mysql-php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de préstamos el cual un profesor solicitara un préstamo, que registrara su número de identificación, la placa o el serial del elemento que solicitara, la fecha actual y al administrador que le presto el elemento en ese momento, que será el usuario que tenga la sesión activa.

El problema que tengo es a la hora de enviar los datos, el navegador no me da ningún error y al mirar la tabla en `phpMyAdmin` los datos no son insertados a la Base de datos.

Este seria el formulario que recibiría los datos y los enviaría a procesarPrestamo.php 
Los valores de $Admin Y $Instructor son de tipo numérico y de $elemento son de tipo String y $fecha tipo date aunque la estoy insertando como cadena por que la consulta preparada solo me permite especificar con "i" para entero "s" para cadena, y "d"para double, en la base de datos,Si la tengo especificada como tipo fecha no se si halla problema con los datos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="procesarPrestamo.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  Elemento: <input type="text" name="elemento"/>
  Cedula:   <input type="text" name="cedula"/> 
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 
include_once 'conexion.php';

session_start();    

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

$Admin = $_SESSION['user'];
$Instructor = $_POST['cedula'];
$Elemento = $_POST['elemento'];
$Fecha = date("d/m/Y");    

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo VALUES(?,?,?,?)") ){

    $stmt->bind_param("iiss",$Admin,$Instructor,$Elemento,$Fecha);     
    $stmt->execute();    
    $stmt->close(); 

} else{
   echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia preparada".$mysqli->error;
}  
$mysqli = new Conexion();  
?>
```

Comment: Hola @AndresDavidRodriguez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías agregar un poco más de detalle en la pregunta? ¿Qué valores tienen `$Instructor` y                                                                                          `$Elemento`, se reciben bien? Deberías seguir el ejemplo de http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php y ver si se genera algún error al ejecutar la consulta, de modo de incluir esta información en la pregunta. Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: 1. Como ya se ha dicho, faltan los nombres de las columnas en el `INSERT` 2. Si sigues dejando `$mysqli = new Conexion(); ` al final del código no... funcionará. 3. Si `$Admin` y `$Instructor` son del tipo `Integer` yo los convertiría a dicho tipo, por ejemplo: `$Admin=intval($_SESSION['user']);` 4. ¿De qué tipo, en la BD, es el campo al que quieres insertar la variable `$Fecha`?

Comment: @Mariano para hacer la edicion, me pedía que ingresara más caracteres. Saludos!

Comment: @Mariano perfecto! buen dato. Muchas gracias!

Comment: En la base de datos, que tipo es FECHA?

Answer (score 1):

El error esta que se te ha olvidado seleccionar tus *columnas* en tu *tabla*, solamente has añadido sus valores.

```
INSERT INTO prestamo (faltan tus columnas)  VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Ejemplo actualizado:

```
session_start();    

include_once 'conexion.php';                            

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

$Admin = $_SESSION['user'];
$Instructor = $_POST['cedula'];
$Elemento = $_POST['elemento'];
$Fecha = date("d/m/Y");    

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo (ccAdmin,ccInstructor,idElemento,fechaPrestamo) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");  
if (false===$stmt) {        
    exit('Sentencia prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}            

$rc = $stmt->bind_param("iiss",$Admin,$Instructor,$Elemento,$Fecha);
if (false===$rc) {      
    exit('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}


$rc = $stmt->execute();
if (false===$rc) {
    exit('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
//Cerramos sentencia
$stmt->close();
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "centrologistico");

/* verificar conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallo: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//UTF-8.
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: agregue las columnas como las tengo en la tabla de la base de datos pero sigue sin suceder nada, no me aparece ningún error pero tampoco me inserta los datos  el fragmento de codigo que cambie quedo de esta forma:"if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo(ccAdmin,ccInstructor,idElemento,fechaPrestamo) VALUES(?,?,?,?)") )"

Comment: @andresdavidrodriguez puedes añadir tu `conexion.php` a tu pregunta, aver si viene el problema desde tu conexión, asi a simple vista no veo ningun error, otra cosa importante que session_start() sea el comienzo, no tu conexión.

Comment: @andresdavidrodriguez te he actualizado el ejemplo de como podría quedar tu conexión (Estilo por procedimientos), te dejo el manual donde podrás ver ejemplos completos https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: No es necesario poner las columnas... [+ info](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187905(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: ¡Gracias por el consejo @aldanux!

Comment: @aldanux _No es necesario poner las columnas..._ ¿Estás seguro? Estamos hablando de una **consulta preparada**. Si no se ponen las columnas, **¿cómo adivinará a qué columna debe asignar los valores?**

Comment: @A.Cedano - Si... siempre y cuando en `VALUES` tengas todas los campos declarado...y en orden

Comment: @aldanux Como muestras en el enlace se puede... admito que no lo sabía, pero de todos modos **nunca lo haría ni nunca lo recomendaría** ya que podría propiciar con mucha facilidad la introducción de valores equivocados en la BD (un valor en una columna diferente) y porque el tratamiento de `NULL` (que debería también ser enviado en el caso de valores `AUTOINCREMET` ) puede variar de una BD a otra o de un lenguaje a otro.

Comment: @A.Cedano - totalmente de acuerdo contigo... solo quería aclarar que es posible :)

Comment: @AndresDavidRodriguez te he actualizado mi ejemplo, para que te muestre algún mensaje de error en tu sentencia `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

a mi parecer puede llegar a verificarlo de la siguiente manera, no se mucho de msqli ya que me gusta mas PDO pero pruebe lo siguiente y muestrenos el mensaje de error en cuyo caso este.

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO prestamo (admin,instructor,elemento,fecha) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("iiss",$Admin,$Instructor,$Elemento,$Fecha);

    if ($stmt->execute()){  
       echo "Se ejecuto la sentencia ";
     } else{
       echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia preparada".$mysqli->error;
     }

     $stmt->close();
```

Con respecto al error puede llegar a ser por el formato de la fecha, en algunos casos puede dar problemas con la parametrizacion de esta.

***Como sugerencia:***

Yo te Recomendaria que te pasaras a PDO http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

Apartando las correcciones de sintaxis que ya se hicieron, me gustaría complementar un poco con mi experiencia, en caso de que alguien esté en la misma situación.

Me daba un error similar (no insertaba y no arrojaba errores), y al dejar de pasar el valor de la hora (en mi caso eran 3 campos y uno era la hora), funcionaba correctamente.

Gracias a un comentario de aquí, comprobé que el error era porque estaba tomando ese dato con la función `time()` de PHP, y luego la reemplace por `date("G:H:s")` y sí insertaba correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar y revisando pude determinar que el valor de una de las variables la enviaba vacía ($sede="" y era $sede="01") y por eso no insertaba el registro.
Revisa que cada una de las variables ($Admin,$Instructor,$Elemento,$Fecha)  tengan un valor válido de acuerdo a su tipo de datos al insertarlas.